# Subset Sum With Paired Values

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, combinations, computation-theory, subset-sum

I have paired values, exactly food objects which have

```
int carb_value;
int protein_value;
int fat_value;
int calories;
```

as data fields.

I'm trying to find all possible food combinations(allowing repetition) for a given search value combination within a 10% error margin for each field. 
i.e.

For a search query of

```
search_carb_value = 40;
search_protein_value = 30;
search_fat_value = 10;
search_calories = 800;
```

and an example Food set of

```
Hamburger = {30,20,10,600}
MilkShake{10,10,0,200}
Pasta{40,15,8,500}
Fish{3,15,3,280}
ChickenSalad{21,16,4,370}
```

The result should be

```
Option 1: Hamburger,MilkShake
Option 2: Pasta,Fish
Option 3: ChickenSalad,ChickenSalad
```

I'm aware of SubSet problem and it's solutions but I can not find anything similar to this or come up with a solution for something like this.

Comment: You need to define how error is to be calculated and how do you combine the errors for each value to get to threshold of 10%?

Comment: I edited that part specifying each filed can have 10% error margin regardless of others.